# Getting values of the caller method using PostSharp

Tags: reflection, postsharp

I have Method2(args...), which is called by Method1(args...). I would like inside the Method2 get the list of VALUES of the arguments of the Method1. It's not possible to do using reflection API, and I red that AOP (PostSharp, Spring.NET) can help. But I wasn't able to find any example.

```
void Main()
{
    Method1(12, "the beatles")
}

void Method1(int number, string str)
{
    Method2("any value");
}

void Method2(string anything)
{
    Console.WriteLine(<argument_values_passed_to_Method1>); // output - 12, "the beatles"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This requirement looks unusual out of the context. For example, it's not apparent why you couldn't pass all the needed parameters to Method2, or store them in the class fields.

One use case I can imagine is `Method2` being a common logging method, that can be called from anywhere in your code. PostSharp, indeed, can help you to implement this in a clean way.

Instead of writing a method, you would need to create an *aspect* class and derive from [`OnMethodBoudaryAspect`](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/T_PostSharp_Aspects_OnMethodBoundaryAspect). Then override some of the methods, based on the point inside the method where you need to inject new logic (*OnEntry*, *OnExit*, *OnException*, ...).
Inside the overridden method you receive [`MethodExecutionArgs`](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/T_PostSharp_Aspects_MethodExecutionArgs), and it gives you access to the method parameters, return value, exception thrown and so on. You can event modify these values in your aspect.

Below is an example of the aspect that will log the parameter values on method entry:

```
[Serializable]
public class LogParametersAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is called with parameter values: {1}",
                          args.Method.Name,
                          string.Join(", ", args.Arguments));
    }
}
```

You apply the aspect to your code by adding it as an attribute:

```
[LogParameters]
void Method1(int number, string str)
{
    // ...
}
```

You also need to install the PostSharp NuGet package into your project to let PostSharp post-process your project and introduce all the aspects.

More information about creating your own aspects can be found in [documentation](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/method-decorator).